# hiding movieclip, rendering performance

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, rendering

I'm developing a rendering engine for a game i am currently building..

I have a main camera (rectangle) that determines what needs to be rendered (thing within it's boundaires)

I am using a bitmap rendering method for the background and that all works fine.

but for the character i am using a movieclip over the top.

when the character goes out of the camera's view is it 100% neccesary to set visible=false?

atm the game is running at 30 FPS (as intended) and everything is sweet, i just wanted to ask out of curiosity.

Is flash clever enough to not bother with movieclip outside of the scene boundaires?

Thanks in advance,
Rory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e3e.html Flash won't render if an object is outside of Stage boundaries:

> **Display list**
>
> The hierarchy of display objects that will be rendered as visible
>   screen content by Flash Player and AIR. The Stage is the root of the
>   display list, and all the display objects that are attached to the
>   Stage or one of its children form the display list (even if the object
>   isn’t actually rendered, for example if it’s outside the boundaries of
>   the Stage).

Answer (score 2):

In my experience display objects added to the stage cause a performance hit even if they are not rendered.

Setting visible to false causes a much lower performance hit, but still a *small* hit.

Removing unnecessary display objects from the display list is a [documented performance tip from adobe](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS948100b6829bd5a66f2268f12913a0c073-8000.html) as well.

Of course, if you only have a few dislay objects it might not be worth the effort, but if we talk about large amounts of display objects I strongly recommend removing them from the display list.